# How to invoke a web service with secret key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, web-services, postman

I have to invoke a webservice of our client. I have the end URL and the secret key. I passed the secret key in the header section. I invoked the webservice. Response from the
service is "Your Authorization secret was not set" and response status is "400 Bad Request". So I strongly suspect that syntax is an issue. I only have the end url
and the secret key. So I tried passing secret key in header section and parameters section but I am getting the same response.

Client has given an example of how to do this on shell script.
(Key and URL are changed for privacy)

`*curl -s --data-urlencode 'secret_key=nJ2RoMRYKzBVQz0AAn1Gvnw5Zb41PE0Wgf4buXKYh9t7ebicC9P1L1Spxx911Rbj4khhhhhhhhhhhgfddssreser'
'https://xyz.corp.yyyy.com/aws/api/getAWSCreds.php?userId=xyz&request=xyz'*`

So I executed it on power shell and the response is:

`*vphp?userId=isoauto&request=getRoleCreds'
Invoke-WebRequest : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
'https://xyz.corp.yyyy.com/aws/api/getAWSCreds.php?userId=xyz&request=xyz'
At line:1 char:1
+ curl -s --data-urlencode 'secret_key=nJ2RoMRYKzBVQz0AAn1Gvnw5Zb41PE0Wgf4buXKY...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand*`

How to fix this?

Comment: What does the documentation say for this API call? We can only guess what the endpoint expects.

Comment: This is what they have given in the instructions:                                             
curl -s --data-urlencode 'secret_key=<SECRET KEY>' 'https://xyz.corp.yyyy.com/aws/api/getAWSCreds.php?userId=xyz&request=xyz?userId=<GENERIC USER NAME>&request=xyz'

Comment: [`curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/windows/) is a program (commonly used on Linux but also available for Windows) that does something that seems pretty similar to [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6)... and based on the error, it appears that you may be typing `Invoke-WebRequest curl -s ...` which seems like an invalid combination of two different commands.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I am just executing curl -s -data ...